# image stretches on setting as Background to GridLayout

Tags: android, layout

I have a scenario where I need to set a bitmap as background to gridLayout. 
I used the following code:

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
bgView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable );
```

Where bgView is GridLayout bitmap is bitmap which I receive from remote server .

The above sets the image as background , but it stretches . 
I need the image to be centered in background .
Can anyone help me in sorting this issue of how to center background image .

Answer (score 0):

Some ago, i have same situation.
i solved this by putting `ImageView` as Background.
it looks like this:

`grid_item.xml`

```
<FrameLayout>

  <!-- wrap original with FrameLayout then put ImageView as bg! -->
  <ImageView />

  <OriginalLayout>
    ...
  <OriginalLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and if `OriginalLayout` is `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout` or something like that,
you don't have to wrap with `FrameLayout`

Hope it hint you to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another bitmap that can fill your grid layout without stretching. Personally, I prefer to fill complete background by fill it in canvas (by zooming it) then crop it further also known as center crop. i found this code :

```
public Bitmap scaleCenterCrop(Bitmap source, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int sourceWidth = source.getWidth();
    int sourceHeight = source.getHeight();

    // Compute the scaling factors to fit the new height and width, respectively.
    // To cover the final image, the final scaling will be the bigger 
    // of these two.
    float xScale = (float) newWidth / sourceWidth;
    float yScale = (float) newHeight / sourceHeight;
    float scale = Math.max(xScale, yScale);

    // Now get the size of the source bitmap when scaled
    float scaledWidth = scale * sourceWidth;
    float scaledHeight = scale * sourceHeight;

    // Let's find out the upper left coordinates if the scaled bitmap
    // should be centered in the new size give by the parameters
    float left = (newWidth - scaledWidth) / 2;
    float top = (newHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;

    // The target rectangle for the new, scaled version of the source bitmap will now
    // be
    RectF targetRect = new RectF(left, top, left + scaledWidth, top + scaledHeight);

    // Finally, we create a new bitmap of the specified size and draw our new,
    // scaled bitmap onto it.
    Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, source.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, targetRect, null);

    return dest;
}
```

Usage : Get your bitmap from remote server (Ist Argument), Width and Height of Grid Layout (IInd and IIIrd Argument) and use returned bitmap as a background of your grid layout.

Hope it will help. (PS : It will not increase your view hierarchy other wise one more solution is to take imageview behind your grid and set its scale type centerCrop and set background image in it).